# How to stop files from saving in /run/user/1000/doc?

Tags: files, kdenlive, location

I use `Kdenlive` for video editing.  All files used to be savable wherever I wanted.  Now, there is no way to PREVENT files from being saved to `/run/user/1000/doc`.  Not only is it annoying and taking time to locate but it's never happened before.  Now it seems to be the default saving location.

Any help for me?  I don't know much about Linux or terminal command lingo.  Have gotten in trouble before with copy paste commands that stuck me in root and caused many other issues in the past.

Comment: You might be using the snap version of kdenlive, and replacing it with the APT version can fix it. Enter the commands `sudo snap remove kdenlive` and `sudo apt install kdenlive`. Let us know if that helps.

Comment: try something simple: sudo chmod ugo-rwx /run/user/1000/doc